# How can you run a piece of code on different subsets in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that I have to modify.
I want to run a piece of different code for different subsets in the dplyr pipeline.
The data handles glycaemia values in patients in ICU.
It looks like this:

```
dfavg <- df %>%
  group_by(patientid) %>%
  mutate(icuoutcome = ifelse(row_number() != n(), 0, icuoutcome)) %>%
  mutate(strata = days) %>%
  mutate(survtime = max(days)-days) %>%
  group_by(days, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(gly_mean = mean(glycaemia))
```

However, I need this code only for the first 5 days a patient is in the ICU.
After this I need another code to run for days 6 to 15.
I tried using filter(days<=5) but then I lose all other data.
How can I make my code so that the upper code runs for day 1-5, another code for 6-15, but all in the same dataset or same pipeline.
I also thought of unfiltering but I don't think that's possible and also of using group_by with a condition (like days<=5).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` the data based on the 'days' and apply the `list` of corresponding functions on the `list` output

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split(df, df$days > 5) %>%
    map2(funslist, ~ .y(.x))
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
split(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$vs) %>% 
     map2_dbl(list(mean, max), ~ .y(.x))
```

Comment: So I split the data, make a list of all separate functions needed for that part of the data and then use map2 to run those functions for that data? I presume then it is not possible in one dplyr piping?

Comment: @JorandeBock. You can create a list of functions as `list(mean, max)` and then apply.  As I don't know your second function or an example data to test, I couldn't possibly write it here

Comment: Is it a possibility to use filter(days<=5), run the code and give this dataset name 'dfavg1', then filter the original dataset for days 6-15, run another code and give it name 'dfavg2' and then join those two datasets together?

Comment: @JorandeBock yes, that is possible, but `map2_dfr` would give a ssingle data.frame output